# Checking for independence in simple Bayessian network

Tags: probability, bayesian-network

Having the simple model, for example
$P(W\mid R)= 0.8$
Is probability of wet grass given rain and
$P(W\mid S)= 0.6$
Is probability of wet grass given sprinkler,
It is correct, that the $P(W \mid S,R)$, if $S$ and $R$ would be statistically independent, is calculated as following:
$$P(-W \mid R)=0.2$$
$$P(-W \mid S)=0.4$$
$$P(-W \mid S,R) = 0.2*0.4 =0.08$$
$$P(W \mid S,R) = 1-0.08 = 0.92$$

The questions are:

- Is this inference correct, again, given independence of $S$ and $R$?
- why do we calculate it using multiplication of negative probabilities and do not use positive probabilities in some way?
- If given $P(W \mid S,R)$ would be unequal to $0.92$, would that be that $S$ and $R$ have conditional dependencies towards each other?
- Why if $W$ is given, $S$ and $R$ became dependent anyway?

Comment: I think your third computation is incorrect. We say A and B are conditionally independent given C if $P(A,B|C) = P(A|C) P(B|C) = P(A|B,C) P(B|C)$.

Comment: C is not given here, and it is correct - i just tested it numerically in similation. You can really sum parents like 1-(1-p1)(1-p2)..., if there are no futher conditions

Comment: Independence does not imply conditional independence. We are given S and R are independent but we do not know if S and R are independent of W. Do we know that P(R,S|W) = P(R|W)P(S|W)?